# Search functionality in WPf forms

Tags: wpf, search

I have my Main form with thousands of records with the user names. I want to implement the search functionality on this form. I planning to do this on textchange event of search textbox (full text search kind of) , like text extender control in web. we can say google search box functionality , I want to implement in WPF. But don't want to fetch records on each key hit from database. It should be manage on UI level only. what have to do? I am using c#, VS 2008. sql server as backend and for communication with db using Linq to SQL.

**Edited:**
Intention is , is there any possibility to search in loaded list on UI level. like in web we usually do by javascript or Jquery, is there remedy for XAML ? or its controls ?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use a grid view control like Xceed Grid or from other vendors that have different "views" that you could use and they already have collection mechanism for cached data.plus they come with filter and you can implment your own search based on the grid data collection